# RxSwift | Initialize and push UIViewController in closure

Tags: ios, swift, closures, system.reactive, deinit

For example we have three UIViewControllers:
**A, B, C**.

1. We pushing **B** from **A**.
2. In B we calling some API:

```
func getProduct(productNumber: String) {
        someService.rxGetProduct(productNumber: productNumber)
            .asObservable()
            .trackActivity(loading)
            .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] product in
                guard let `self` = self else { return }
                let cViewModel: CViewModel = .init()
                let cViewController: CViewController = .init(viewModel: cViewModel)
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(cViewController, animated: true)
            }, onError: { [weak self] error in
                // error handling
            }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

3. In method above, we are getting some product model and pushing **C** view controller in closure.

The problem is, when we are popping back from **C** view controller to **B** view controller – **C** view controller is not deinitializing. **C** view controller is deinitializing when we are popping back from **B** view controller to **A** view controller.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

1. You might be creating the retain cycle within `trackactivity` or whatever `loading` is
2. consider using `take(1)` and `asSingle()` in case your observable is not intended to complete.